# Javascript Changing the index in memory of two identical objects

Tags: javascript, object

I have found some people saying to use JSON but that said that another function wasn't defined and I've also tried `Object.assign()` my issue is I have 2 identical objects however when I modify one the other changes its because they have the same index in memory is there any way to prevent this in js Thanks in advance :)

For example:

```
var obj1 = {
    info: 5
}
var obj2 = obj1;
obj2.info += 1;
console.log(obj1.info == obj2.info) //returns true I don't want it to
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are trying to do. Could you elaborate with some code?

Comment: @Basillicum he has two references to the same object while he wants to different identical objects.

Comment: If they're identical, they're not *two* objects but just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want `obj2` to be a reference to `obj1`, then you have to define it with its own keys/values, like this:

```
var obj1 = {
  info: 5
};
var obj2 = {
  info: 5
};

console.log(obj1 == obj2); // false - they are not the same object
obj2.info += 1;
console.log(obj1.info == obj2.info); // false
```

Even though the two objects *look* identical and start with the same key and value, they will not be treated as equal. If you have a big object with lots of keys (and nested keys) that you don't want to keep re-typing, you'll have to write a deep copy function to fully re-create the object.